Manhua/manhwa where the male main character has a system that makes him do missions where, once complete, he travels to other worlds
The main character has white hair and some sort of irresistible charm that attracts women. The first world he was in was a cultivation world. He sometimes goes to another world and becomes another person. One such role was some kung fu master. Each time he completes a world's mission, he gets an ability from that world. Another world had zombies. He eventually has some kind of dimensional place where his women can stay in as well.
